# SwiftでviewWillAppearメソッドが呼び出されません。

Tags: swift, ios, uikit

お世話になっております。

画面Aと画面Bがあり、画面Aの上に画面Bを配置しており、
画面BをPOPするときに、画面AのviewWillAppear()メソッドで
処理をしたいのですが、画面AのviewWillAppear()メソッドが
呼び出されず困っております。

ネットで調べた所、
「iOS13から仕様変更で、
　viewWillAppear()メソッドが呼び出されないようになった。」
とのことがわかりました。

ただ、画面AのviewWillAppear()メソッドがコールされるタイミングで
行いたい処理があるのですが、皆さんどう実現されているのでしょうか。

ソースコードは、以下になります。

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    presentingViewController?.beginAppearanceTransition(false, animated: animated)
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    print("viewWillAppear was called.")
}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    presentingViewController?.endAppearanceTransition()
    
    initializeDisplay()
    
    print("viewDidAppear was called.")
}
```

宜しくお願いいたします。

Comment: [こちらのスレッド](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/49034/13972)は参考になりませんか?

Answer (score 0):

上記の質問ですが、自己解決いたしました。

下記ページの対応にて解決いたしました。
https://tn-works.jp/ios13-pagesheet/

ありがとうございます。